# "user validation failed: passsword: Path `passsword` is required."

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Here is my Mongoose model:

```js
    const mongoose=require('mongoose')

const userSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
    firstName:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    middleName:{
        type:String,
    },
  
    lastName:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
    },
    passsword:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    email:{
        type:String,
        unique:true,
        sparse:true
    },
    phoneNumber:{
        type:Number
    },
    address:{
        permanentAddress:String,
        temporaryAddress:[String]
    },
    gender:{
        type:String,
        enum:['male','female','others']
    },
    dob:{
        type:Date
    },
    country:{
        type:String,
        default:'Nepal'
    },
    image:{
        type:[String]
    },
    role:{
        type:Number,
        default:2
    },
    isArchived:{
        type:Boolean,
        default:false
    },
    status:{
        type:String,
        enum:['active','inactive','frequent'],
        default:'active'
    },
    passwordResetTOken:String,
    passwordResetTokenExpiry:String
})


const userModel=mongoose.model('user',userSchema)
module.exports=userModel
```

The controller is:

```js
    function insert(data){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        const newUser=new userModel
        newUser.password = passwordHash.generate(data.password)
        newUser.firstName=data.firstName
        newUser.lastName=data.lastName
        newUser.dob=data.dob
        console.log("new user is",newUser.password)
        console.log("mapped user is",newUser)
        newUser.save(function(err,done){
             if(err){
                 return reject(err)
             }
             console.log("user is",done)
             resolve(done)
         }) 
    })

}
```

I am getting error:

```
                    "name": "ValidatorError",
                "message": "Path `passsword` is required.",
```

But `req.body` has:

```js
     {
  firstName: 'rajiv',
  lastName: 'dahal',
  password: 'admin',
  dob: '2021/03/03'
}
```

What is my mistake?

Answer (score 3):

You have a typo when defining User Schema. You have 3 `s` instead of 2 for the name of **password** property. Just update you User Schema:

pa**sss**word -> pa**ss**word

Answer (score 2):

should be password not passsword

```
passsword:{
  type: String,
  required: true,
},
```